# .bat file runs on its own, but not when called by scheduled task

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

On my backup server, I have two tasks to run: An SQL Dump and an SQL Import each set to run at **01:00** and **02:00** respectfully.

The dump creates a zipped .SQL file by **1:45** AM every time. 
The import is supposed to extract the file and import it.

According to Task Scheduler, both tasks run successfully, however, my backup server's local database only has data from my last manual backup. This makes sense because the total runtime of my import task is about 12 seconds.

If I run the backup "manually" by double clicking my **import_db.bat** script in the file explorer, it works perfectly after running for about 30 minutes.

If I run the backup from task scheduler by right clicking and choosing "Run", it runs for 12 seconds without doing anything. History says it ran successfully.

**Import Task Settings:**

- Run with highest priviledges
- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Action -> Start a program | C:\FILEPATH\import_db.bat (no args)
- Allow tasks to be run on demand
- Stop the task if it runs longer than [2 hours]
- If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop

**Snippets of the import script:**

```
mysql -u root -p"xxxxxx"< "C:\FILEPATH\import_db.sql" --verbose
copy C:\FILEPATH\import_mirror_db.sql C:\FILEPATH\archives\backup[date].sql.zip
```

There must be something I'm doing wrong in Task Scheduler, but research seems to tell me I'm doing everything correctly. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The second I whine about something and give up, I seem to find a solution. This fixed it.

**For the task, under "Actions":**

- **Program/Script:** [  import_db.sql  ]
- **Start in:** [  C:\FILEPATH  ]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have solved the issue by adding **file's directory** in **Start in (option)** input box.

Full path in Program/script Input box and directory path in Start in input box.